# Firebase admin deleteUser function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to delete all the users in my auth and database using firebase functions. Here's my code for that:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
   
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: "----"
});
export const listenToAdminCommands = functions.firestore.document('collection/{docUid}')
  .onWrite((change, context) =>
  {
    const pass: string = '--';
    // const before = change.before.exists? change.before.data() : null;
    const after = change.after.exists? change.after.data() : null;

    if(after !== null && after !== undefined) {
      const adminCommandType: string = after['type'];
      const adminCommandPass: string = after['pass'];

      if(adminCommandType === 'deleteAll' && adminCommandPass === pass) {
        adminDeleteAllUsers();
      }
    }
  });
//Admin control
function adminDeleteAllUsers() {
  deleteAllUsers(' ');
  return null;
}
function deleteAllUsers(nextPageToken: any) {
  admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then((listUsersResult: any) => {
      //go through each one and check last time signed in
      listUsersResult.users.forEach((userRecord: any) => {
        const user: any = userRecord.toJSON();
        const userUid = user['uid'];
        console.log('Deleting user for data delete uid = ', userUid);
        admin.auth().deleteUser(userUid)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('Successfully deleted user', userUid);
          })
          .catch((error: any) => {
            console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
          });
          db.collection('users').doc(userUid).delete();
      });
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
      }
    })
    .catch((error: any) => {
      console.log('Error listing users:', error);
    });
}
```

When the function get executed, no user is deleted. It's like the function never worked. Am I missing something?

Update:
I'm not sure if this is the way to do it, but it's still not working. I tried to handle promises correctly, but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct or not.

```
export const listenToAdminCommands = functions.firestore.document('collection/{docUid}')
  .onWrite((change, context) =>
  {
    const pass: string = '---';
    // const before = change.before.exists? change.before.data() : null;
    const after = change.after.exists? change.after.data() : null;

    if(after !== null && after !== undefined) {
      const adminCommandType: string = after['type'];
      const adminCommandPass: string = after['pass'];

      if(adminCommandType === 'deleteAll' && adminCommandPass === pass) {
        return adminDeleteAllUsers();
      }
      return;
    }
    return;
  });
//Admin control
function adminDeleteAllUsers() {
  return deleteAllUsers(' ');
}
function deleteAllUsers(nextPageToken: any) {
  return admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then((listUsersResult: any) => {
      //go through each one and check last time signed in
      listUsersResult.users.forEach((userRecord: any) => {
        const user: any = userRecord.toJSON();
        const userUid = user['uid'];
        console.log('Deleting user for data delete uid = ', userUid);
        return admin.auth().deleteUser(userUid)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('Successfully deleted user', userUid);
            return db.collection('users').doc(userUid).delete();
          })
          .catch((error: any) => {
            console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
            return;
          });
      });
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
      }
      return;
    })
    .catch((error: any) => {
      console.log('Error listing users:', error);
      return;
    });
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire function.  What you have here isn't enough.  We need to see how this function is invoked by the greater function, and how its results are handled.  I will say right now that you're not handling promises correctly.  The function needs to return a promise that resolves when all of the async work is complete.

Comment: @DougStevenson Added the rest of the code

Comment: You're definitely not dealing with promises correctly at all as I described in my first comment. See the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions